# how to eleminate a div from triggering a scrollbar?

Tags: css, scrollbar

I have a situation where I have a wrapper div that has 840px width.
Now inside that div I put an decorative element (#dekoschrift) that is not so important and that overlaps the wrapper div. I don't want the horizontal scrollbar to be triggered from that element.

here's roughly the situation:

```
<div class="centerer">
    <div id="wrapper">
          <div id="dekoschrift"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the css:

```
.centerer { position: relative; width: 830px; margin: 0 auto; height: 100%; }
#wrapper { position: relative; float: left; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
#dekoschrift { 
      background:  url(/images/layout/Variaton_Typogrund.png) no-repeat 0 0 transparent; 
      width: 238px; height: 524px; 
      position: absolute; top: 280px; left: 845px; z-index: 0; 
    }
```

is that somehow possible?

I've tried to set "overflow: hidden" to the wrapper div, but that obviously cut's the graphics. And I cannot use "overflow-x: hidden" on the body because that would make it impossible to scroll on a small screen.

here's the link to the actual page: 
www.variaton.ch

any help appreciated!
maybe there's some secret "display: secretly" parameter that I don't know of?!

cheers
stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a media query. You can disable scrolling for displays which don't *need* to scroll and then pop in the scroll bar when it's mandatory.

```
body {
    overflow-x : hidden;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
    body {
        overflow-x : auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man! this is an interesting solution and it seems to work without a problem! although I will put the overflow-x: hidden also in a media query... just in case a browser doesn't support media queries. but anyways! thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
.dekoschrift
{
visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: that is really not going to work! I don't even have to give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

so the final code looks like that:

```
   @media all and (min-width: 840px) {
        body {
            overflow-x : hidden;
        }
    }

    @media all and (max-width: 840px) {
        body {
            overflow-x : auto;
        }
    }
```

thanks Alienwebguy